# Flask: Save session data with redirect

Tags: flask

I am using sessions to store products info to shopping cart. Now that works, however when I add it to the session and then redirect to the cart view, the newly added product id is not saved.

```
class CartAddProduct(View):

    def dispatch_request(self, product_id):
            
        print("*** Product id to add: ", product_id)
        if not 'cart' in session:
            session['cart'] = []

        product_info = {}
        product_info['product_id'] = str(product_id)
        product_info['amount'] = 1
        print("going to append: ", product_info)
        print("before: ", session['cart'])
        session['cart'].append(product_info)
        print("after: ", session['cart'])

        return redirect(url_for('cart'))
```

Response:

```
*** Product id to add:  5
going to append:  {'product_id': '5', 'amount': 1}
before:  [{'amount': 1, 'product_id': '9'}]
after:  [{'amount': 1, 'product_id': '9'}, {'product_id': '5', 'amount': 1}]
```

But then after I redirect to "cart" and I print it, its unchanged. The session does not pass with the redirect?

```
[{'amount': 1, 'product_id': '9'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `session.modified = True`

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session

> Be advised that modifications on mutable structures are **not picked up
> automatically**, in that situation you have to explicitly set the
> attribute to True yourself.

So objects of built-in types like (list, set, dict) are mutable.